# Is the way TimeValue[s, i, {t, t1}] works with s being a Cashflow using date expressions a bug or a feature?

Tags: finance

The documentation for [`TimeValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeValue.html) tells us that in `TimeValue[s,i,t]` we can have *s* be a [`Cashflow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cashflow.html) and that we may define the relevant accounting or discounting period using `{t,t1}` instead of simply *t*. The documentation for `Cashflow` tells us that we may provide *times*  for the cash flow as date expressions. Whenever times for `TimeValue` are specified as dates "*all interest rates are assumed to be annual rates.*"

With these explanations in mind, we can try a simple example:

```
TimeValue[ Cashflow[ { { {2010,1,1}, -600 } } ], 0.1, {2012, 1, 1} ]
(* -726. *)
```

This is plausible considering that the equivalent continuous compounding annual rate for *10%* is `Log[1.1]` and accordingly:

```
-600 Exp[ Log[1.1] * 2 ] (* compound for 2 years *)
(* -726. *)
```

Ok, but what is happening in the following case using `{t, t1}` to specify a *reference point*  for cash flow occurences to compute "*the time value accumulated or discounted from time t1 to t using interest i.*"

```
TimeValue[ Cashflow[ { { {2010, 1, 1}, -600 } } ], 0.1, { {2012, 1, 1}, {2010, 1, 1} } ]
(* -878.46 *)
```

As we can easily check this is equivalent to compounding for 4 periods:

```
-600 Exp[ Log[1.1] * 4 ]
(* -878.46 *)
```

Is this a bug or a feature, e.g., is there some reasoning behind the use of `{t,t1}` in this case?